# How to connect/communicate Pod to DocumentDb which is outside eks cluster but within same VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, kubernetes-pod, aws-documentdb

I want to deploy my full stack application using AWS EKS, with the backend pod connected to the databases(MongoDB hosted on AWS managed service) outside of the cluster. If the EKS cluster and the databases are in same VPC, how should I configure the pod to connect exterbal database but within same VPC.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need a bit more details, but see if this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/deploy-amazon-rds-databases-for-applications-in-kubernetes/) gives you an idea about how to accomplish this.